# In mssql 2019 where sqlcmd utility is?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I am working on the tool that will silently deploy SQL server instance and I need to run a few scripts after installation, but I struggle to find where SQLCMD utility is.

For example, I use this:

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,SDK

But after installation is finished there is no SQLCMD on the system.

Where is it?

**UPDATE**:

I've managed to create a silent installation that includes sqlcmd tool with this:

FEATURES=SQLENGINE,Tools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have MSSQL 2019 installation at my PC and could figure out the path. You can find this tool in the below directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn
```

You may also download it fresh from below links:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142258

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2142257

[Same is documented here on MS site.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver15)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've just found it with [where sqlcmd.exe] now it seems it differs from one version to another, do you know if it is a part of FEATURES=SDK?